# TinyMCE not able to load content when called for second time in one page in Mozilla

Tags: ajax, firefox, tinymce

Basically,I have loaded tinyMCE on the textarea. And my motive is :

When the button is clicked, the editor should be filled by the description stored in 
database through ajax call.

It works properly in Chrome.

But when I run the script in Firefox,it works fine for the first time. But  on pressing the button again, the description flashes for a second and disappears. The code works fine on refreshing the page .

What could be problem? Any help would be helpful.

Comment: Would be helpful to see the code you are using.

Comment: Basically,it's a bug of firefox 11. TinyMCE 3.4 works fine.Other TinyMCE 3.5.2 doesn't work.Thanks.

Comment: Without your code people on StackOverflow will be unable to replicate what you see and propose solutions.

Comment: Sorry for replying late.Basically,I tried 3.4 and it worked.It was a bug of Firefox 11.It works fine in later version.Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There are several possibilities.

One can be that you need to shut down the tinymce editor instance before reinitializing it a second time.

To shut down an edtor instance use:

```
tinymce.execCommand('mceRemoveControl',true,'editor_id');
```

To reinitialize use

```
tinymce.execCommand('mceAddControl',true,'editor_id');
```

Comment: in order to find out what's wrong we need some more information about your code and what you tried so far

Answer (score 0):

```
tinymce.init({
        mode : "exact",
        selector: 'your_textarea_selector',
        theme: "modern",
        plugins: [
              "advlist autolink lists link image charmap print preview anchor",
              "searchreplace visualblocks code fullscreen",
              "insertdatetime media table contextmenu paste"
        ],
        toolbar: "insertfile undo redo | styleselect | bold italic | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | link image",
        toolbar_items_size: 'small',
        image_advtab: true,
        init_instance_callback : function(editor) {             
            var currentEditor = editor.editorContainer;
            $(currentEditor).show();
        }
    });
    if (tinymce.editors.length>0) {
        tinymce.execCommand('mceFocus', true, txt_area_id);
        tinymce.execCommand('mceRemoveEditor',true, txt_area_id);
        tinymce.execCommand('mceAddEditor',true, txt_area_id);
    }
```

> This works fine for me even with ajax requests. I'm using Tinymce 4.x in my JSP.

Answer (score 0):

This thing works for me:

You need to call the tinyMCE script from the very page which is containing the editor.

I am using MVC4 Razor framework. By injecting this code on my page helped me:

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/scripts/tinymce/tinymce.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```